# Why text properties are overridden in this context?

Tags: string, text-properties

I'm trying to understand why text properties are overridden when creating a list inside a function. I'm wondering if it is expected or a bug.

For example, if I create a list of fruits like this, each element of the resulting list preserve their text properties:

```el
(setq fruits nil)
(setq apple-red "an apple")
(add-text-properties 0 (length apple-red) '(color red) apple-red)
(setq apple-green "an apple")
(add-text-properties 0 (length apple-green) '(color green) apple-green)
(push apple-red fruits)
(push apple-green fruits)

;; fruits:
;; (#("an apple" 0 8
;;    (color green))
;;  #("an apple" 0 8
;;    (color red)))
```

However, if I want to refactor this code by doing the add inside a function, then previously element added in the list got their text properties overridden by the last added element text properties, for example:

```el
(defun add-apple-to-fruits (color)
  (let ((c color)
        (apple "an apple"))
    (add-text-properties 0 (length apple) `(color ,c) apple)
    (push apple fruits)))

(setq fruits nil)
(add-apple-to-fruits "red")
(add-apple-to-fruits "green")

;; fruits:
;; (#("an apple" 0 8
;;    (color "green"))
;;  #("an apple" 0 8
;;    (color "green")))
```

Comment: That is because the function is destructively modifying the same string literal `"an apple"` each time it is called. Any global occurrences of that string may be modified by side effect.  As a general rule, you should never destructively modify self-quoting literals like `"an apple"` or `'(an apple)`. You can instead use `propertize`, for example, which returns a copy of the string with the desired text properties. See [`(info "(elisp) Mutability")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mutability.html).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: @Basil: Please move your comment info to an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable (here or on the internet). OP: please consider accepting Basil's answer, once he creates it.

Comment: @Drew I'd be surprised if this topic didn't already exist as a Q&A.

Comment: @Basil Then maybe the Q should be deleted as a dup...